# Connect Samsung Galaxy tab 2 P3100 to a GPS dongle/ Receiver

Tags: usb-on-the-go, external-gps

I have a Samsung galaxy tab 2 p3100. I have an android application which uses its internal GPS to get Latitude, Longitude values. But the lat, long values getting from this tab is not accurate. So I want to connect an external GPS Dongle / receiver to tab and get lat, long values from the external device instead of from tab.
I want to know is there any external GPS Dongle / receiver device that supports Galaxy tab2  or any other android device? And if yes, which is the device and how to connect it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available to you, but make sure that you know that the app you're using supports them!

You can go with a Bluetooth GPS receiver like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0018YZ836). Reviewers mention that it works with Android, but not iOS. One reviewer says it works perfectly, another says that not all apps work with it. (I'm inclined to believe that the user who mentions that it needs an app is mistaken)

You can also get a USB bluetooth receiver [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PKX2KA) one with an OTG Cable [like this](http://compare.ebay.com/like/251214287494?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar), but these are designed to be used with PC hardware, so support for Android may or may not be very good.

I would personally go with the bluetooth option for convenience and because there are others who have done it with Android devices already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am afraid these devices are not available in India. I am trying to find out if I can get these in any shopping site in India. I will get back to you if I get any one for more info on these.

Comment: The same kind of devices are probably available in India, even if it's not the same brand name. The links I included are only examples.